# Different functionality between ARM SMMU and x86 IOMMU?

Tags: x86, arm, virtualization, iommu

I have survey some I/O virtualization things.
And I found that IOMMU is a key hardware component for hardware-assisted I/O virtaulization.

How about the ARM SMMU?
Is there any difference between ARM SMMU and x86 IOMMU?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, clearly there will be, much like the architectural differences between an ARM MMU and an x86 MMU. Since you haven't asked a specific question, I'd suggest looking at [ARM's architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.memory/index.html) vs. [Intel's architecture](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/intel-technology/vt-directed-io-spec.html) for whatever you're interested in.

Comment: The x86 I/O MMU is typically per device.  [tag:trust-zone] is structured to give the CPU some capabilities to dynamically switch device permissions.  Here, ARM delegates the protection to each master and slave device with the bus controller propagating the permission; but only allowing *secure* and *normal*.  The *smmu* looks like it tries to provide multiple permissions.